# C non-blocking keyboard input blocks on run level 3 (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, io, ubuntu-18.04, tty

I have a piece of code that reads in the keyboard input (used for debugging purposes), implemented in C on Ubuntu 18.04. Since other processes have to run on the same thread, it is initialised as non-blocking.

When I try to run my application on run level 3, it blocks when trying to read in a keyboard character. This behaviour does not occur when I run the application on run level 5.

Does anyone have any answer as to why the behaviour is inconsistent between these two run levels?

This is the code (not shown: where the read operation is called by the application's main loop):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>


static int fd;

int kbd_initModule()
{
    fd = open("/dev/tty", O_NONBLOCK | O_NOCTTY);

    if(fd < 0)
    {
        ERROR("Unable to open keyboard: %d", fd);
        return fd;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int kbd_deinitModule()
{
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

int kbd_getEvent()
{
    uint8_t buf[1];

    int tmp = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));

    if(tmp == -1)
    {
        ERROR("%s", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return buf[0];
    }
}
```

I am available to answer any questions and provide additional details.

**Additional details:**

- Launch app: run level 5: `sudo ./app` ; run level 3: `sudo xinit ./app` (there are GUI components in the app, so X server must be started on run level 3 - would be good if someone knew more about this).

Comment: How are you running the program?

Comment: Run level 5: `sudo ./app` ; run level 3: `sudo xinit ./app`

Comment: So that's one thing that needs to be in the question: *you are using a different command to run the app.* Also, how do you know whether it blocks or doesn't block?

Comment: `xinit` manually launches an X display server (since we are running in CLI mode under run level 3). Do you know whether that could interfere with I/O? Presumably `xinit` is called automatically when we launch under run level 5... We know the function doesn't block under run level 5 as the other application processes are running correctly, which is not the case under run level 3.

Comment: So you see that other processes don't run, and you assume that therefore, reading from /dev/tty must be blocking?

Comment: I mean that I can follow the execution of the application right up until `read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));`, after which no more instructions are executed. Putting prints before/after this instruction proves as much, insofar as the first print is displayed, whereas the second is not. The app does not crash either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** Turns out if you intialise to the current tty device on runlevel 3, it does not work. Initialising to a specific tty device (in this case tty3) resolves the issue.

Not really sure why this is the case (maybe the default tty on run level 3 is the X window?), would appreciate if someone could explain why this happens.